# How to remove switch to convert string to generic function

Tags: c#, generics, dry

This is probably a newbie question but I couldn´t find a good answer even googling and reading a lot about the subject.

I have a generic method, lets call it Execute()

My code receives a message1:

```
 {
   serviceProvider: "Sever1",
   serviceType: "query",
   service: "authors"
 }
```

and message2 could be:

```
 {
   serviceProvider: "Sever2",
   serviceType: "query",
   service: "bookTitles"
}
```

Now, I have

```
public void ProcessMessage(Message message)
{
   switch (message.service)
   {
      case "authors":
        Execute<Authors>();
        break;
      case "booTitle":
        Execute<BookTitle>();
        break;
   }
}
```

I really don´t like this ProcessMessage method, as it does not look DRY at all. And if we add more types of services, then we need to keep adding to the switch.

How should I implement this thing? Do I need reflection? I´d rather not use reflection as the ProcessMessage can be called thousands of times and reflection would probably add a lot of overhead.

Comment: What's the code you _want_ to write?  `Execute(message.service)`?

Comment: So far, looks like you don't need the strong types `Authors` or `BookTitle` to accomplish whatever `Execute<T>` will do.  (No implementation provided in your example, so I can't tell.)

Comment: you can also look at the Source Generators feature to generate your switch statement at compile time with zero-overhead in the runtime. Reflection, even a highly-optimized implementation, will be times slower then simple switch statement and this may be critical in case of thousands calls.

Comment: "thousands of times" probably won't make a significant difference in performance. I'd start with reflection, because it's relatively simple, and then consider more advanced options like Source Generators only if you find it's going too slow.

Comment: Honestly in my opinion the switch for different types isn't nearly so bad as the fact that you're switching based on a string in the Message object. Any chance of changing that to an enum or something? As for the repeating Execute<T>(); it's difficult to say without seeing what's inside Execute.

Comment: Sorry for not making things clear.  This code is just an example,  The Execute<T> is in a library and it requires a type.  The code is not about Authors and Books but deals with getting market data from an exchange.  "Thousands of times" (per second).  As for the switch, it is actually based on an Enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a dynamic switch you don't need to resort to reflection, but you'd need to register the services you want to use.

Based on your question, here's what that might look like:

```
void Main()
{
    this.Register("authors", () => Execute<Authors>());
    this.Register("bookTitles", () => Execute<BookTitle>());
}

private Dictionary<string, Action> _registry = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

private void Register(string key, Action action)
{
    _registry[key] = action;
}

public void ProcessMessage(Message message)
{
    if (_registry.ContainsKey(message.service))
    {
        _registry[message.service]();
    }
}
```

You can add as many actions as you need. And you can do that at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

My answer will be split into Two sections:

## Section 1: Tell you what you really need!

I think Services dont add so often, so you shouldn't optimize the Maintenence aspect of this code,
just add a strong ASSERT if a service call is not recognized,
so while testing, you know you forgot to add it to this function!

## Section 2: give you what you asked for!

I think you can use reflection, but to compansate for performance,
you should cache the Function calls in a dictionary.

```cs
 // psuedo C#

auto m_ServiceCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SERVICE>()

public void ProcessMessage(Message message)
{
  Action svcFunction;
  if(!m_serviceCache.TryGetValue(message.service, out svcFunction))
  { // not found in cache
     // create the service specific instanciation, and save it to cache!
    // Take into account that the "message.service" needs to be a valid type name with namespace!
     // Also note you should Sanitize the input as it is a very clear vaulnerablity to exploit
     // totally abstract psuedo here

     getGeneralType = typeof(SERVICE);
     specificType = getGeneralType.CreateSpecificType(T=message.service)
     specificObject = specificType.Instanciate();
     m_serviceCache.Add(message.service, svcFunction);
     svcFunction = specificObject;
  }
  svcFunction(); // call the cached service.
}
```

cheers

Comment: I'd use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of a normal `Dictionary` for thread-safety, btw, which means also replacing `TryGetValue` with `GetOrAdd` and move the branched code to a factory function.

Comment: @Dai The `ConcurrentDictionary` is good call, fixed, the rest is why I stated it as pseudo c#.